# Using Socket.io with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, socket.io, sequelize.js

I am trying to use Socket.io and Sequelize to create a chat app. Socket.io will handle the socket to allow for instant messaging. Sequelize will handle storing the messages so when you refresh the screen you still have your messages.

What is happening is that on localhost my socket works, but it does not send the messages to the database. When I put it onto Heroku, my database worked, but it does not use the sockets.

My socket is located in `app.js` and my database route is located in `routes/messages.js`.

I have been working on this bug for a while now and I have been trying to get help with it. I think the best way to share this is with my markdown I created detailing my efforts to fix my bug that can be found at [here](https://github.com/jenkaplan/vortxt/blob/master/attempts%20to%20fix%20socket%20database%20issue.md). My repo for this can be found [here.](https://github.com/jenkaplan/vortxt)

Comment: Are you using ECMA6?

Comment: @aguertin Yes I am using ES6.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different parts that you need to distinguish:

- the HTTP server, in your code represented by the variable `http`
- the Express app, represented by `app`
- the Socket.IO server, represented by `io`
- a Socket.IO (client) connection (see below)

The HTTP server directs "normal" HTTP requests to the Express app, which will handle them according to the middleware and routes that are set up. A router handler gets called with (at least) two arguments, generally called `req` and `res`, to represent the (incoming) HTTP request and the (outgoing) HTTP response.

The Socket.IO server gets to handle specific Socket.IO requests, which get sent to the server by the Socket.IO client (running in the browser). When such a client sets up a connection with the server, the `connection` event gets triggered on the server. Any handlers for this event will get passed an argument, generally called `socket`, that represents the (bidirectional) connection with that client.

That Socket.IO connection can receive messages (sent from the client running in the browser), which trigger events on the socket. You can install a handler to listen for particular messages (like *"chat message"*), which will receive, as argument, the data that was sent to it by the client.

The issue in your code seems to be with setting up everything to handle those chat messages. The correct setup order would be:

- listen on the Socket.IO server for `connection` events
- when such an event is received, add a listener for the `chat message` event on the connection
- when such an event is received, write the data to the database.

In code:

```
// Listen for new client connections.
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  // Listen for the client to send a _"chat message"_ message.
  socket.on('chat message', function(data) {

    // Store the data in the database.
    models.Messages.create({
      message  : data.message,
      username : data.username
    });

  });
});
```

As you can see, `req` and `res` aren't available inside of those Socket.IO event handlers, because those are only used for normal HTTP requests.

Also, as opposed to HTTP, you don't necessarily have to send anything back to the client when you have received a message, so I left that part out. The handler above only writes the message data to the database (it also doesn't check for, or handle, errors, which eventually you should add).

Comment: I think that is the right track, however, now I am getting this error. `Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Messages" ("id","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,'2017-03-30 04:20:30.667 +00:00','2017-03-30 04:20:30.667 +00:00') RETURNING *;
Unhandled rejection SequelizeBaseError: null value in column "message" violates not-null constraint`. I have the full error listed last in the markdown with my attempts [here](https://github.com/jenkaplan/vortxt/blob/master/attempts%20to%20fix%20socket%20database%20issue.md) It seems that it is not reading the message in the message box now.

Comment: That error suggests that the `Messages` table/model requires that the field `message` always contains a valid value. The insert statement you're showing doesn't set that field, hence the error.

Comment: Hm, the insert statement? Do you mean this from views/messages/index.ejs `<input id="m" autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Your Message" />`? The value I'm trying to add is a message that I typed into that input. When I hit submit it says it is null, but I know I typed a message into the form.

Comment: You can see in the insert statement in the error message that `message` is not being set. Also, how are you sending the form data to the Socket.IO server? And lastly: you can easily insert a `console.log(data)` before the insert/create statement to see what the data actually contains.

Comment: I am getting the same error. It looks like the insert statement isn't being triggered since it isn't console logging anything. I am pushing these changes up to GitHub for you to see.

Comment: That sounds like your frontend isn't sending any messages over Socket.IO to the server, or is sending them incorrectly. You should check a few things (for instance, using some more `console.log` statements): does the frontend code reach the part where the message is sent to the server, is the message it's going to send correct, does the server's `connection` event trigger appropriately, etc.

Comment: Okay I'm sorry about that, the data is being passed in. When I console logged data it is showing me the message I typed in followed by that error message.